# Yii Flash Messages not showing - possible HTTP Proxy browsing?

Tags: yii, proxy

I'm investigating a problem a user is having with a web application that is built using Yii.

The user is not seeing the Yii 'flash' session-based user-feedback messages. These messages are shown once to a user and then destroyed (so they're not shown on subsequent page loads).

I took a look at the server access logs and I noticed something weird.

When this user requests a page there is a second identical request but from a different IP and with a different User Agent string. The second request is often at the same time or is sometimes (at most) a couple of minutes later. A bit of googling leads me to the conclusion that the user is browsing the web using a HTTP Proxy.

So, is this likely to be a HTTP Proxy? Or could it be something more suspicious? And if it is a HTTP Proxy, does this explain why they're not seeing the flash session messages? Could it be that the messages are being 'shown' to the Proxy and then destroyed?

Comment: Yii flash message is session based variable and it has once using mechanism. please check whether page is re-rendered or not .

Comment: @RamkrishnaChaulagain Yes, I think that somehow this particular user is browsing the pages in such a way that they ARE being re-rendered, but before the user is seeing them. But is this possible? Is this a faulty Proxy or is this the expected outcome of Proxy browsing or is this something else? I suppose my question is really more about Proxy browsing (if that's what this is) than Yii flash messages.

Comment: Couple questions: 1) Is the problem peculiar to just one user? 2) Is the problem peculiar to one page/url path?

Comment: @ragingprodigy 1) It has only been reported from a single user, but there's only 3 or 4 in total. 2) I don't have confirmation of this. The issue was reported only in relation to a single page but it's possible it's happening on other pages.

Comment: Are AJAX requests "proxied"?  If not, I'd try to make AJAX Flash messages.